# How to add multiple servers to a LoadBalancer in Hetzner Cloud with Terraform?

Tags: loops, cloud, terraform

Currently trying to get the new [Hetzner Load Balancer](https://www.hetzner.com/cloud/load-balancer) working with multiple servers using Terraform v0.12.28.
Provided [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hetznercloud/hcloud/latest/docs/resources/load_balancer) shows only case of one sever which is quite weird for a load balancer :)

Servers are created using *count* like this:

```
 resource "hcloud_server" "web" {
  count       = var.instances
  name        = "web-server-${count.index}"
...
}
```

and to add a server to the load balancer one should use the pattern like this:

```
    target {
    type = "server"
    server_id = hcloud_server.web.id
  }
```

Yet any kind of *for* or *for_each* seems not applicable here to add all created instances.

Could you please show me the direction how to add count-created servers to the load balancer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) could be used in your situation.

You could possibly do something similar to the following (dynamic block is the `target`; example from docs, so it may require adjustment to your real code):

```
resource "hcloud_load_balancer" "load_balancer" {

  name       = "my-load-balancer"
  load_balancer_type = "lb11"
  location   = "nbg1"


  dynamic "target" {

    for_each = hcloud_server.web

    content {
        type = "server"
        server_id = target.value["id"]
    }   

  }

}
```

Comment: @YevhenOrestov Sorry, I think it should be `server_id = target.value["id"]`. I updated the answer. This is an example, you have to modify it to your own code.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to do the same and I ended up changing the type of the target from server to label.

On each resource you can set a label, for example "env=dev" and then on your load balancer you use the type label, and then label_selector to match your label.

Example:

```
resource "hcloud_server" "node1" {
  name = "node1"
  image = "debian-9"
  server_type = "cx11"
  labels = {"env" : "dev"}
}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer" "load_balancer" {
  name       = "my-load-balancer"
  load_balancer_type = "lb11"
  location   = var.instance_location
}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer_target" "load_balancer_target" {
  type             = "label_selector"
  load_balancer_id = hcloud_load_balancer.load_balancer.id
  label_selector   = "env=dev"
}
```